# Parsing GLSL error messages

Tags: opengl, glsl

When I compile a broken GLSL shader then the NVidia driver gives me error messages like this:

```
0(102) : error C1008: undefined variable "vec"
```

I know the number inside the brackets is the line number. I wonder what the `0` at the beginning of the error message means. I hoped it would be the index in the sources array which is passed to `glShaderSource` but that's not the case. It's always `0`. Does someone know what this first number means?

And is there some official standard for the error message format so I'm able to parse the line number from it or do other OpenGL implementations use other formats? I only have access to NVidia hardware so I can't check how the error messages are looking like when using AMD or Intel hardware.

Comment: Why do you want to 'parse' compile errors in the first place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a file name, which you can't specify via GL API, so it is 0.

You can set it with `#line num filename` preprocessor command right within shader code. Could be helpful if your shader is constructed from many files with `#include`s via external preprocessor (before passing source to GL).

There is no standard for messages. Everyone doing whatever they want.

Comment: Nice. Is this `#line` macro an OpenGL standard or vendor specific?

Comment: It is included in GLSL ES specification. I'm sure 'big' GLSL have it too.

Comment: Ok, works fine. Thanks. But it should be noted that `filename` is not a file name (string), it is also just a number. So I guess when I'm not able to parse the error message (Because all vendors use their own formatting) I have to output a list of filenames which were involved in constructing the full shader source so the user can see in which file the error actually can be found.

Comment: Hm thanks, just realised GLSL specification doesn't support full C `#line` and only allows 'source-string-number' instead of filename. Nvidia is very likely to allow both though (at least `cgc` allows that, which is almost the same compiler they use within GL implementation), but it isn't portable :-(

Answer (score 2):

glShaderSource accepts an array of source strings. The first number is the index into that array.